# DT::datatable won't render results in HTML R markdown report

Tags: r, r-markdown, dt

I have an HTML R markdown template that I've been using for a while to render reports.  I mainly use `DT::datatable()` to report the results in the markdown report so I can use the copy button extension to copy the results into another document for final processing/formatting.  Up until about a week ago, this was working fine.  However now, my markdown report will only render the first table printed with `DT::datatable()` in the report.

I dived down into the raw HTML of the report and found that the first table renders as expected:

[image: HTML of first table]

However, when I look at where the second table is supposed to be, the table doesn't appear to be getting rendered properly:
[image: HTML of second table]

Even if I just use `DT::datatable()` with the default options, it won't render:
[image: HTML of third table]

The complete markdown document and the rendered report are at https://github.com/jrf1111/July13_SO_issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue.  In my first call to `DT::datatable` I used `DOM = 'B'` to enable buttons, but I didn't include `t`.  For some reason that allowed the first datatable to render properly but prevented any further calls to `DT::datatable` from rendering.  Setting `DOM = 'Bt'` in the first call to `DT::datatable` fixed everything.